# How do I apply :hover to multiple bem statements in sass?

Tags: css, sass, bem

I have this:

```
.magic-sparkles {

    &-red {
        background: red;
    }

    &-blue {
        background: blue;
    }

    &-green {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

However I want to change it so it only works on hover.

The end result compiled would be:

```
.magic-sparkles-red:hover { background: red;}
.magic-sparkles-blue:hover { background: blue;}
.magic-sparkles-green:hover { background: green;}
```

Changing the first line to `.magic-sparkles:hover {` does not work. Do I need to simply add `:hover` to every single nested item or is there a way to apply it to all of them simultaneously?

Comment: Just &:hover? should be that

Comment: Do I need to simply add :hover to every single nested item? - Yes.
Or you can create your scss function but when there is only 3 items there is not much sense in it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work:

```
:hover.magic-sparkles {
    &-red {
        background: red;
    }

    &-blue {
        background: blue;
    }

    &-green {
        background: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Clever, I didn't think of that!

Comment: This is incredible. Been writing CSS for 10+ years and never thought of that.

Answer (score -2):

html:

```
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="parent red"></div>
<div class="parent blue"></div>
<div class="parent green"></div>
```

scss:

```
.parent{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  &.red{
    background-color: red;
  }
  &.blue{
    background-color: blue;
  }
  &.green{
    background-color: green;
  }
  &:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

[I made a pen how you could achieve this][1]

```
[1]: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RmdzWE
```

Yes you can apply same hover effect on all elements

Comment: If you want to apply other hover effects on the different elements you need to nest them further

Comment: Please include the code in the answer. Otherwise when CodePen goes down, or this pen gets deleted, this answer loses all value.